# moodle $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly

Tags: moodle

This is basically the problem, I've read that the folder must be outside the public html and it could be the permission, but I tried both of them and I still could not solve it, what else could it be?

I did 2 things before the problem started:

1. created a subdomain named master
2. used git pull in the public_html to update the website

I have updated the same way before and this problem had never happened. I didn't rewrite anything because the log doesn't show anything related to the moodle, or the data folder of the moodle.

Answer (score 3):

The Moodle use a data folder to store content such as document or picture files uploaded by users, it's best create this folder outside of your web host folder.

After the Moodle installation it's created the config.php file in the Moodle installation folder, there you have:

```
$CFG->dataroot  = 'data folder location';
```

You can try setup the data folder path manually, if the config.php file doesn't exist maybe you don't have permission to write files on the server disk/folder.